# Duplicate map is being added to list

Tags: dart

```
void main() {
  Map firstMap = { "id": 1, "value": [{"key": "A"}, {"key": "B"}]}; 

  List<Map> newList = [];

  List valueList = firstMap["value"];

  for(int y=0; y<valueList.length; y++) {
    Map newMap = firstMap;
    newMap["value"] = [{"key": valueList[y]["key"]}];

    newList.add(newMap);
  }

  print(newList);
}
```

My expectation for `newList` is to look like:

```
[{id: 1, value: [{key: A}]}, {id: 1, value: [{key: B}]}]
```

but the actual value of newList is

```
[{id: 1, value: [{key: B}]}, {id: 1, value: [{key: B}]}]
```

I am not sure what to try here.

`valueList[y]["key"]` seems to have the correct value in each iteration.

The code above has been shared as a link here to dart pad.

How would I achieve the same? Also what is going on with my code, which is leading to such a result.

[Open with Dart pad](https://dartpad.dartlang.org/4c817e152229dd30a63746b4c9e38326)

Comment: `Map newMap = firstMap;` is taking a reference to `firstMap`, not a copy. I think this is the root cause. I didn't try to fully understand what you are trying to accomplish.

Comment: I am trying to make a list of two items(both maps), where in on has `key` equal to A and the other has `key` equal to B. I have mentioned my expected result in the question.

Comment: Also the list does have `{id: 1, value: [{key: A}]}` in the first iteration of the loop,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Error that you are doing is as already mentioned in the comment, reassignment to different variable does not make a copy of data:

```
Map a = {"a": 1}
Map b = a;  // b is just one more reference to same object

b["a"] = 2;

print(a); // ->    {"a": 2}
```

Transformations from one shape to another can be conveniently done with [map()](https://api.dartlang.org/stable/2.1.0/dart-core/Iterable/map.html)

https://dartpad.dartlang.org/8283e91c2c201ddb65ef073e76995f1d

```
void main() {
  Map firstMap = { "id": 1, "value": [{"key": "A"}, {"key": "B"}]};

  List valueList = firstMap["value"];

  List<Map> newList = valueList.map((valueItem) => {
    "id": firstMap["id"],
    "value": [valueItem]
  }).toList();

  print(newList);
}
```